# Optional parameter in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have below method in vuejs

```
methods: {
    show () {
    }
}
```

In this `show()` method often I would like to pass parameter, often I would not like to pass parameter when I'll call it HTML. Like `show (obj)` and `show ()`

How can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
methods: {
    show (obj) {
        if(obj) {
            // code to be executed if obj was passed
        } else {
            // code to be executed if no obj was passed
        }
        // code to be executed regardless 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also set a optional value by using a function parameter default value. See [this vuejs example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56673411/how-can-i-set-default-parameter-value-in-vue-js-method-function/56673412#56673412)