# How can I set default parameter value in Vue.js method function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to set a default parameter value for a function in one of my component methods like:

```
methods: {
    myFuntion(isAction = false) {}
}
```

But when debug the value of isAction I get a "MouseEvent"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. It looks like the event is also passed to the method by default. Therefore you can set a default parameter value on a method function like:

```
methods: {
    myFuntion(event, isAction = false) {
        // isAction will be false by default
        // event will have the contain the event object
    }
}
```

Comment: Nit: default values is modern JavaScript syntax, so drop the legacy `function` and just use: `myFuntion(event, isAction = false) {`

Answer (score 4):

1. If you call your method like below, it will **implicitly pass** the event object:

```
<button @click="myFuntion">Default Action</button>
<!-- isAction will be event -->
```

2. If you don't need the event object, just **add the parenthesis** to the method name:

```
<button @click="myFuntion()">Default Action</button>
<!-- isAction will be false -->
```

3. Otherwise, simply pass the value for isAction:

```
<button @click="myFuntion(true)">Special Action</button>
<!-- isAction will be true -->
```